# Scope changed when nav back view content

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flot

I'm working on a admin page using angularjs, flot plugin. I'm trying to draw a chart on my Dashboard content. I wrote a directive like this:

```
.directive('ngChartDirective',function(){
    return {
        controller : 'chartCtrl'
    };
});
```

this is ma div in Dashboard content:

```html
<div class="jarviswidget" ng-chart-directive id="wid-id-0" data-widget-togglebutton="false" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-fullscreenbutton="false" data-widget-colorbutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false">
                <!-- widget options:
                usage: <div class="jarviswidget" id="wid-id-0" data-widget-editbutton="false">

                data-widget-colorbutton="false"
                data-widget-editbutton="false"
                data-widget-togglebutton="false"
                data-widget-deletebutton="false"
                data-widget-fullscreenbutton="false"
                data-widget-custombutton="false"
                data-widget-collapsed="true"
                data-widget-sortable="false"

                -->
                <header>
                    <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats txt-color-darken"></i> </span>
                    <h2>Live Feeds</h2>

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right in" id="myTab">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#s1"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span class="hidden-mobile hidden-tablet">Live Stats test</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#s2"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <span class="hidden-mobile hidden-tablet">Social Network test</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#s3"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> <span class="hidden-mobile hidden-tablet">Revenue</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </header>

                <!-- widget div-->
                <div class="no-padding">
                    <!-- widget edit box -->
                    <div class="jarviswidget-editbox">

                        test
                    </div>
                    <!-- end widget edit box -->

                    <div class="widget-body">
                        <!-- content -->
                        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade active in padding-10 no-padding-bottom" id="s1">
                                <div class="row no-space">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <span class="demo-liveupdate-1"> <span class="onoffswitch-title">Live switch</span> <span class="onoffswitch">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="start_interval" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="start_interval">
                                                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="start_interval"> 
                                                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner" data-swchon-text="ON" data-swchoff-text="OFF"></span> 
                                                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span> </label> </span> </span>
                                        <div id="updating-chart" class="chart-large txt-color-blue"></div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 show-stats">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <span class="text"> My Tasks <span class="pull-right">130/200</span> </span>
                                                <div class="progress">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-color-blueDark" style="width: 65%;"></div>
                                                </div> </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <span class="text"> Transfered <span class="pull-right">440 GB</span> </span>
                                                <div class="progress">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-color-blue" style="width: 34%;"></div>
                                                </div> </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <span class="text"> Bugs Squashed<span class="pull-right">77%</span> </span>
                                                <div class="progress">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-color-blue" style="width: 77%;"></div>
                                                </div> </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <span class="text"> User Testing <span class="pull-right">7 Days</span> </span>
                                                <div class="progress">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-color-greenLight" style="width: 84%;"></div>
                                                </div> </div>

                                            <span class="show-stat-buttons"> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-block hidden-xs">Generate PDF</a> </span> <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-block hidden-xs">Report a bug</a> </span> </span>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="show-stat-microcharts">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                                        <div class="easy-pie-chart txt-color-orangeDark" data-percent="33" data-pie-size="50">
                                            <span class="percent percent-sign">35</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="easy-pie-title"> Server Load <i class="fa fa-caret-up icon-color-bad"></i> </span>
                                        <ul class="smaller-stat hidden-sm pull-right">
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="label bg-color-greenLight"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i> 97%</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="label bg-color-blueLight"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> 44%</span>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="sparkline txt-color-greenLight hidden-sm hidden-md pull-right" data-sparkline-type="line" data-sparkline-height="33px" data-sparkline-width="70px" data-fill-color="transparent">
                                            130, 187, 250, 257, 200, 210, 300, 270, 363, 247, 270, 363, 247
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                        <div class="easy-pie-chart txt-color-greenLight" data-percent="78.9" data-pie-size="50">
                                            <span class="percent percent-sign">78.9 </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="easy-pie-title"> Disk Space <i class="fa fa-caret-down icon-color-good"></i></span>
                                        <ul class="smaller-stat hidden-sm pull-right">
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="label bg-color-blueDark"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i> 76%</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="label bg-color-blue"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> 3%</span>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="sparkline txt-color-blue hidden-sm hidden-md pull-right" data-sparkline-type="line" data-sparkline-height="33px" data-sparkline-width="70px" data-fill-color="transparent">
                                            257, 200, 210, 300, 270, 363, 130, 187, 250, 247, 270, 363, 247
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                        <div class="easy-pie-chart txt-color-blue" data-percent="23" data-pie-size="50">
                                            <span class="percent percent-sign">23 </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="easy-pie-title"> Transfered <i class="fa fa-caret-up icon-color-good"></i></span>
                                        <ul class="smaller-stat hidden-sm pull-right">
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="label bg-color-darken">10GB</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="label bg-color-blueDark"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i> 10%</span>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="sparkline txt-color-darken hidden-sm hidden-md pull-right" data-sparkline-type="line" data-sparkline-height="33px" data-sparkline-width="70px" data-fill-color="transparent">
                                            200, 210, 363, 247, 300, 270, 130, 187, 250, 257, 363, 247, 270
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                        <div class="easy-pie-chart txt-color-darken" data-percent="36" data-pie-size="50">
                                            <span class="percent degree-sign">36 <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="easy-pie-title"> Temperature <i class="fa fa-caret-down icon-color-good"></i></span>
                                        <ul class="smaller-stat hidden-sm pull-right">
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="label bg-color-red"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i> 124</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="label bg-color-blue"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> 40 F</span>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="sparkline txt-color-red hidden-sm hidden-md pull-right" data-sparkline-type="line" data-sparkline-height="33px" data-sparkline-width="70px" data-fill-color="transparent">
                                            2700, 3631, 2471, 2700, 3631, 2471, 1300, 1877, 2500, 2577, 2000, 2100, 3000
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- end s1 tab pane -->

                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="s2">
                                <div class="widget-body-toolbar bg-color-white">

                                    <form class="form-inline" role="form">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="s123">Show From</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="s123" placeholder="Show From">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="s124" placeholder="To">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="btn-group hidden-phone pull-right">
                                            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> More <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-file-text-alt"></i> Export to PDF</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-question-sign"></i> Help</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

                                    </form>

                                </div>
                                <div class="padding-10">
                                    <div id="statsChart" class="chart-large has-legend-unique"></div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- end s2 tab pane -->

                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="s3">

                                <div class="widget-body-toolbar bg-color-white smart-form" id="rev-toggles">

                                    <div class="inline-group">

                                        <label for="gra-0" class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="gra-0" id="gra-0" checked="checked">
                                            <i></i> Target </label>
                                        <label for="gra-1" class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="gra-1" id="gra-1" checked="checked">
                                            <i></i> Actual </label>
                                        <label for="gra-2" class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="gra-2" id="gra-2" checked="checked">
                                            <i></i> Signups </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="btn-group hidden-phone pull-right">
                                        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> More <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-file-text-alt"></i> Export to PDF</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-question-sign"></i> Help</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="padding-10">
                                    <div id="flotcontainer" class="chart-large has-legend-unique"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end s3 tab pane -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- end content -->
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- end widget div -->
            </div>
```

and my controller:

```
.controller('chartCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
    $scope.request = function(){
    var result;
    console.log("requesting");
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://angularjs.khonet.com/datasource/database.php?type=chart-data'})
            .then(function (response) {
            result=response.data;
            $scope.chartData=result;console.log('done');
        });
    };

    $scope.firstLoad = function(callback){
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://angularjs.khonet.com/datasource/database.php?type=chart-data'})
                .then(function (response) {
                result=response.data;
                $scope.chartData=result;
                console.log('start callback');
                callback();
        });
    };
    $scope.startCall = function(){
            $scope.inv=setInterval(function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.request();
            });
        },1500);
    };
    $scope.endCall = function(){
        clearInterval($scope.inv);
    };

}])
```

and here's my script in dashboard view to draw this chart:

```
var data = [],
            totalPoints = 200,
            $UpdatingChartColors = $("#updating-chart").css('color');

        // setup control widget
        var updateInterval = 1500;
        $("#updating-chart").val(updateInterval).change(function () {

            var v = $(this).val();
            if (v && !isNaN(+v)) {
                updateInterval = +v;
                $(this).val("" + updateInterval);
            }

        });

        // setup plot
        var options = {
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            },
            xaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            },
            colors: [$UpdatingChartColors],
            series: {
                lines: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                            opacity: 0.4
                        }, {
                            opacity: 0
                        }]
                    },
                    steps: false

                }
            }
        };
        var plot = undefined;
        var scope = angular.element($("#wid-id-0")).scope();
        scope.firstLoad(function(){
            var tempData = scope.chartData;
            plot = $.plot($("#updating-chart"), [tempData], options);
            console.log('callback end');
        });
        /* live switch */
        $('input[type="checkbox"]#start_interval').click(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $on = true;
                updateInterval = 1500;
                scope.startCall();
                update();
            } else {
                //var scope = angular.element($("#wid-id-0")).scope();
                scope.endCall();
                clearInterval(updateInterval);
                $on = false;
            }
        });

        function update() {
            if ($on == true) {
                //console.log('updated');
                if(Array.isArray(scope.chartData)) {
                    plot.setData([scope.chartData]);
                    plot.draw();
                }
                setTimeout(update, updateInterval);

            } else {
                clearInterval(updateInterval);

            }

        }

        var $on = false;
```

now I nav to any content then back, there's an error on my console:

> angular.js:9778 TypeError: scope.firstLoad is not a function
>       at generatePageGraphs (eval at globalEval ...

the scope id has changed. Dude, where's my scope???

**Edit:**
I found that when you put a function in controller like this:

```
$scope.myfunc=function(){console.log('This is my func')};
```

On first load if you log your function you wil see it but if you nav back from another view there are just function name but the code inside will be undefined.
Sorry If you dont understand. My english is not good

**Edit 2:**

This is my demo: [tam.khonet.com](http://tam.khonet.com/)

as you can see in console tab, scope object has text field but I can't access to scope.text. it's undefined. Anyone tell me why please

Comment: PS : It worked fine at the first load.

Comment: Nobody answer??